# Automation logic for Cucumber Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am looking for help for automation logic for below scenario.

I have to create a application(say something like creating a user) in my web app, after creation, through search we can find and open the application with the unique number. Then there will be a File Upload button will be enabled for that application to upload any files. But the catch here is, for the file upload button to get enable, it has to go through couple of workflows inside the system. So approximately it takes 3 to 5 minutes to get the File Upload button to get enabled for that single application created. I am looking for how to automate this case in Cucumber-Selenium-Java.

Because, even though we script, the selenium will not wait for 3-5 minutes for the file upload button to get enable. We manually also cannot do that which is not good practice , which will slow the execution, as I have to create approximately 30 applications, which in case the workflow will be taking each application one by one in sequence to get the File Upload button to get enabled. Because that is how the development design has been made.

So any help or any logic suggestions on how can we automate these type of cases?

Comment: If the button is getting enabled in 5 minutes then there is no other option than to wait for it. If you have many such tests, that would probably make sense to run them in parallel.

Comment: You are saying "the selenium will not wait for 3-5 minutes for the file upload button to get enable."...but there are lot of ways to keep your script on hold for required time.